# How to avoid null value in a select query and replace that value as 0 in a select query not in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select t1.d as Date,t1.S AS StoreNo ,t1.Cash,N3.price,(N3.price-t1.Cash)as Totalsale,ISNUll(t2.gift,0)as Card,ISNULL(t3.coupon,0) as couup
from 
(Select Date as d,StoreNo as S,SUM(DayTotalAmt)Cash
  from POS_FinTtl where (SerialNo like  '23')
  group by StoreNo,SerialNo,Date) t1 

Join (Select Date as d,StoreNo as S, SUM(DayTotalAmt)gift
      from POS_FinTtl where (SerialNo like  '31')
      group by StoreNo,SerialNo,Date) t2 On t1.d =t2.d and t1.S = t2.S
join (Select Date as d,StoreNo as S, SUM(DayTotalAmt)coupon
      from POS_FinTtl where (SerialNo like  '30')
      group by StoreNo,SerialNo,Date)t3 On t2.d =t3.d and t2.S = t3 
Left join (Select BuyDate as d,StoreNo as S ,Sum(SalePrice)as price 
           from POS_TtlTran where StoreNo = 467 
           GROUP BY StoreNo,BuyDate) As N3
        On  N3.d = t1.d and N3.S = t1.S
        Where (N3.S = 467) AND (N3.d >= '6/01/2015') AND (t1.d <= '6/30/2015')



Result 

Date        StoreNo Cash  price  Totalsale Card  couup

2015-06-01  467     14860 88145  73285    78334  2000

2015-06-05  467     23032 76380  53348    40456  19000

2015-06-07  467     44225 133737 89512    95205  5000

2015-06-14  467     78134 110940 32806    30677  11000

2015-06-21  467     76234 166070 89836    97114  6000

2015-06-23  467     19844 46221  26377    29072  1000

2015-06-28  467     91165 127911 36746    40974  6000
```

But date 2015-06-02 couup value 0 but its not extracting from table but other columns as values.

Comment: Your question got badly formatted because you didn't follow the formatting rules.  You can see them with the help link, and you might want to reformat the question to come out nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using conditional aggregation.  The basic query is:

```
Select Date as d, StoreNo as S,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like '23' then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as cash,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like '31' then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as gift,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like '30' then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as coupon,
       SUM(case when StoreNo = 467 then SalePrice else 0 end) as price
from POS_FinTtl 
group by StoreNo, Date;
```

I don't quite follow how the date arithmetic fits in -- either in a `where` clause to apply to all values or the in individual `case` statements.  Wherever it goes, you do not need such a complicated query.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to use, they are all in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/).  For conditional replacement in an expression `IFNULL(var,0)` will return var if it has a value otherwise 0.

Comment: COALESCE() does the stuff too

Comment: Yes, I said there were a number of things.  I mentioned only 1 and referred the OQ to the manual to figure out which was right in his case.

Comment: thanks !! i will try it